# Combinatória e Probabilidade

Tags: r

Quando eu combino por exemplo 4 strings ["A","B","C","D"] 2 a 2, ou seja, AB,AC,AD,BC... eu consigo contar em quantas ocorrências o A e o B apareceram?

Meu problema envolve 16 itens que combinados 4 a 4 geram 1820, mas gostaria de saber em quantos desses 1820 os itens A e B, por exemplo, aparecem juntos ou isolados.

Já consegui gerar o vetor com o combn e o combinations mas não consigo contar.

Comment: A combinação é um produto vetorial em que letras repetidas são excluídas do resultado final. Então a solução é criar um vetor a partir do quadrado do vetor original (usando um nested for loop, por exemplo) e usar um filtro que elimine repetidas e tem as letras de interesse

Answer (score 4):

Uma solução pode ser a seguinte.
Usar a função a aplicar a cada combinação para obter um vetor lógico se ambas (`all`) as letras estão em cada combinação. Uso ainda `which` para dar um vetor numérico, que sem os resultados `FALSE` é mais curto e fácil de apresentar como saída.

```
AB <- LETTERS[1:2]
which(combn(LETTERS[1:16], 4, function(x) all(AB %in% x)))
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
#[23] 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44
#[45] 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66
#[67] 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88
#[89] 89 90 91
```